# How does the 'on grid' node positioning in TikZ actually work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

I thought I knew how the `on grid` option of TikZ (cf. version 2.10 manual section 16.5.3 pages 186-187) worked, but the results I get are different from what I expected.

I have a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[red]
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \node[below=of a,draw] (anode) {};
    \draw[-|] (anode) -- (a);
    \node (b) at (.3,0) {};
    \node[below=of b,draw] (bnode) {};
    \draw[-|] (bnode) -- (b);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[green,dashed]
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \node[on grid,below=of a,draw] (anode) {};
    \draw[->] (anode) -- (a);
    \node (b) at (.3,0) {};
    \node[on grid,below=of b,draw] (bnode) {};
    \draw[->] (bnode) -- (b);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It results in the following figure:

[image: illustration of 'on grid' node positioning option]

I would have expected (and hoped...) that on the left, the dashed green node were positioned at the same height as the dashed green one on the right. (All other picture elements are correct, as far as I can tell.) From the description in the manual, I do not see why this is not the case:

> When you say `above=1cm of somenode` with `on grid` set to true, the new node will be placed in such a way that its center is 1cm above the center of `somenode`.

The only non-standard thing in my example is that then reference node is a `coordinate`, but I do not see why it results in the observed behavior, as this is just a node with only a center.

I would be grateful for an explanation of the observed behavior, and perhaps workaround to get the behavior I expected.

Answer (score 5):

A node will have `inner sep` unless you make it zero yourself, where as a co-ordinate doesn't. And **further a `node` doesn't create a geometric point.** Your code with all `inner sep=0` will give

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[red]
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \node[inner sep=0,below=of a,draw] (anode) {};
    \draw[-|] (anode) -- (a);
    \node[inner sep=0] (b) at (.3,0) {};
    \node[inner sep=0,below=of b,draw] (bnode) {};
    \draw[-|] (bnode) -- (b);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[green,dashed]
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \node[inner sep=0,on grid,below=of a,draw] (anode) {};
    \draw[->] (anode) -- (a);
    \node[inner sep=0] (b) at (.3,0) {};
    \node[inner sep=0,on grid,below=of b,draw] (bnode) {};
    \draw[->] (bnode) -- (b);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the  horizontal red line on right is lower than that on the left even though the `inner sep` is set to zero. (changing `\node[inner sep=0] (b) at (.3,0) {};` to `\coordinate (b) at (.3,0);` will fix it and **this is one option to get things right**.)

Replacing

```
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
```

with

```
\node[inner sep=0cm] (a) at (0,0) {};
```

inside the scope, gives

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[red]
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    %\node[] (a) at (0,0) {};
    \node[inner sep=0,below=of a,draw] (anode) {};
    \draw[-|] (anode) -- (a);
    \node[inner sep=0] (b) at (.3,0) {};
    \node[inner sep=0,below=of b,draw] (bnode) {};
    \draw[-|] (bnode) -- (b);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[green,dashed]
    %\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    %\node[] (a) at (0,0) {};
    \node[inner sep=0cm] (a) at (0,0) {};
    \node[inner sep=0,on grid,below=of a,draw] (anode) {};
    \draw[->] (anode) -- (a);
    \node[inner sep=0] (b) at (.3,0) {};
    %\coordinate (b) at (.3,0);
    \node[inner sep=0,on grid,below=of b,draw] (bnode) {};
    \draw[->] (bnode) -- (b);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Without `inner sep = 0` we will get,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[red]
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0); 
    \node[below=of a,draw] (anode) {};
    \draw[-|] (anode) -- (a);
    \node[] (b) at (.3,0) {};
%    \coordinate (b) at (.3,0);
    \node[below=of b,draw] (bnode) {};
    \draw[-|] (bnode) -- (b);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[green,dashed]
    %\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    %\node[] (a) at (0,0) {};
    \node (a) at (0,0) {};
    \node[on grid,below=of a,draw] (anode) {};
    \draw[->] (anode) -- (a);
    \node (b) at (.3,0) {};
    %\coordinate (b) at (.3,0);
    \node[on grid,below=of b,draw] (bnode) {};
    \draw[->] (bnode) -- (b);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Option -2** Replacing `\node[inner sep=0] (b) at (.3,0) {};` to `\coordinate (b) at (.3,0);` in your code gives

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[red]
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \node[below=of a,draw] (anode) {};
    \draw[-|] (anode) -- (a);
    \coordinate (b) at (.3,0);
    \node[below=of b,draw] (bnode) {};
    \draw[-|] (bnode) -- (b);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[green,dashed]
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \node[on grid,below=of a,draw] (anode) {};
    \draw[->] (anode) -- (a);
    \coordinate (b) at (.3,0);
    \node[on grid,below=of b,draw] (bnode) {};
    \draw[->] (bnode) -- (b);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

> I do not see why this is not the case:
>
> When you say above=1cm of somenode with on grid set to true, the new node will be placed in such a way that its center is 1cm above the
>   center of somenode.
>
> The only non-standard thing in my example is that then reference node
>   is a coordinate, but I do not see why it results in the observed
>   behavior, as this is just a node with only a center.

And I don't know how to answer this, with all the above facts. May be some experts will shed light on this.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer. However, `inner sep` is not the issue; in your version with `inner sep` universally set to zero, you still get the same qualitative behavior as in my version. Also, I can't just change `\coordinate` by `\node` in my code just because the coordinates are points where in and outgoing lines should touch (which is not the case with nodes, even with zero `inner sep`).

Comment: @equaeghe: The idea of `on grid` is meant for use with nodes so that everything is emulated as `on grid`. With coordinates I think it is meaningless. Hence it would be better to use all `nodes` than mixing them with coordinates IMO.

Comment: Sorry, but it certainly does make sense when mixing nodes and coordinates. In my block diagram use case, some nodes correspond to summation blocks, but if only one signal (branch) enters the summation, the summation block is by convention removed, leading me to replace that node by a coordinate. And it would all work perfectly if only the `on grid` positioning option would work consistently with both nodes and coordinates. (I now think the current behavior may be a bug.)

Comment: @equaeghe: :( Sorry I could not help much. :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that on grid and `below = of <name>` seem to have no effect if `<name>` belongs to a `\coordinate` instead of to a `\node` (see the summary diagram at the bottom). You can use a `\node` with `inner sep=0pt` instead of a `\coordinate` (I draw a grid only as a visual help):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines,gray!20] (-1,-2) grid[step=2mm] (1,1);
  \begin{scope}[red]
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \node[below=of a,draw] (anode) {};
    \draw[-|] (anode) -- (a);
    \node (b) at (.3,0) {};
    \node[below=of b,draw] (bnode) {};
    \draw[-|] (bnode) -- (b);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[green,dashed]
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (a) at (0,0) {};
    \node[on grid,below = of a,draw] (anode) {};
    \draw[->] (anode) -- (a);
    \node (b) at (.3,0) {};
    \node[on grid,below = of b,draw] (bnode) {};
    \draw[->] (bnode) -- (b);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The following diagram summarizes the behaviour of the `on grid` option for pairs formed by all possible combinations of `\coordinate`s and `\node`s. Nodes are drawn (the squares in the diagram); small circles are used to show the center for the `\node`s and the positioning of `\coordinate`s.

As can be noticed, using `below = of <name>`, when `<name>` belongs to a coordinate makes `on grid` to have no effect (the red cross on the diagram), and that explains the problem with your original code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3,transform shape,node distance=1cm]
\draw[help lines,gray!20] (-0.5,-2) grid[step=2mm] (7.5,1);
\draw[help lines] (-0.5,0) -- +(-0.6,0);
\draw[help lines] (-0.5,-1) -- +(-0.6,0);
\draw[help lines,<->] (-0.8,0) -- node[fill=white] {\tiny 1cm} (-0.8,-1);

\node[align=left,anchor=south] at (3.5,1) {behaviour of \texttt{on grid} with nodes and coordinates};

% a and b are coordinates (on grid true or false produce the same result)
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate[below=of a] (b);
\foreach \point in {a,b}
{
  \draw (\point) circle (1pt);
  \node[label=left:\tiny\point] at (\point) {};
}

% a and b are coordinates (on grid true or false produce the same result)
\coordinate (a) at (1,0);
\coordinate[on grid,below=of a] (b);
\foreach \point in {a,b}
{
  \draw (\point) circle (1pt);
  \node[label=left:\tiny\point] at (\point) {};
}

% c is a coordinate and d is a node
\coordinate (c) at (2,0);
\node[draw,below=of c] (d) {};
\foreach \point in {c,d}
{
  \draw (\point) circle (1pt);
  \node[label=left:\tiny\point] at (\point) {};
}

% c is a coordinate and d is an on grid node (on grid has no effect)
\coordinate (c) at (3,0);
\node[draw,on grid,below = of c] (d) {};
\foreach \point in {c,d}
{
  \draw (\point) circle (1pt);
  \node[label=left:\tiny\point] at (\point) {};
}
\draw[thick,red] ([yshift=-15pt]d.north west) -- ([yshift=-15pt]d.south east);
\draw[thick,red] ([yshift=-15pt]d.north east) -- ([yshift=-15pt]d.south west);

% e is a node and f is a coordinate
\node[draw] (e) at (4,0) {};
\coordinate[below=of e] (f);
\foreach \point in {e,f}
{
  \draw (\point) circle (1pt);
  \node[label=left:\tiny\point] at (\point) {};
}

% e is a node and f is an on grid coordinate (on grid has effect)
\node[draw] (e) at (5,0) {};
\coordinate[on grid,below=of e] (f);
\foreach \point in {e,f}
{
  \draw (\point) circle (1pt);
  \node[label=left:\tiny\point] at (\point) {};
}

% g is a node and h is a node
\node[draw] (g) at (6,0) {};
\node[draw,below=of g] (h) {};
\foreach \point in {g,h}
{
  \draw (\point) circle (1pt);
  \node[label=left:\tiny\point] at (\point) {};
}

% g is a node and h is an on grid node  (on grid has effect)
\node[draw] (g) at (7,0) {};
\node[draw,on grid,below = of g] (h) {};
\foreach \point in {g,h}
{
  \draw (\point) circle (1pt);
  \node[label=left:\tiny\point] at (\point) {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, using a `\node` instead of a `\coordinate` is not the same thing and might require some additional adjustments, but you can use `inner sep` and `outer sep` to get the desired result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) at (0,0) {};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (b) at (0,1) {};
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=-2\pgflinewidth] (c) at (0,2) {};
\draw (-1,0) -- (a) -- (1,0);
\draw (-1,1) -- (b) -- (1,1);
\draw (-1,2) -- (c) -- (1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't the `below of=` syntax deprecated (by the `below=of` syntax with `on grid`)? [Cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9386]

Comment: This answer provides a (temporary? see comment above) solution to my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @equaeghe the link you provided is broken (I get a "Page Not Found" massage).

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9386 should work (spurious ] at end in my previous attempt)

Comment: @equaeghe you're right. Last night I mixed the syntax (too late, perhaps ;-)). I updated my answer.

Comment: @equaeghe new update with `inner sep` and `outer sep` to make a `\node` behave (up to a certain extent) as a `\coordinate`.