# Block diagram with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

It's the first time I'm using Tikz on Latex. I have to draw this block diagram (this is a low resolution snip from a paper)
[image: block diagram]

In Tikz I have done this:
[image: myblock]

That is very similar but I need some adjustments, like the u_i arrow and the node sum after the H(s) block.

Is there anybody that can help me with this? 
my code:

```
    \tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=white, rectangle, 
minimum height=2em, minimum width=3em]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=white, circle, radius=1mm, node distance=1.5cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
\node [input, name=input] {};
\node [input, above of=input](input1) {};
\node [sum, right of=input] (sum) {};
\node [block, right of=sum] (controller) {$K(s)$};
\node [sum, right of=controller] (sum1) {};
\node [block, right of=sum1] (filterinv) {$H^{-1}(s)$};
\node [block, right of=filterinv] (system) {$G(s)$};
\node [output, right of=system] (output) {};
\node [output, above of=output] (output1) {};
\node [block, below of=filterinv] (filter) {$H(s)$};
\node [block, above of=controller] (delay) {$D(s)$};
\node [sum, below of=sum1] (sum2) {};

\draw [->] (filterinv) -- node[name=u] {$u_{i}$} (system);
\draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$s_{i-1}$} (sum);
\draw [->] (sum) -- node {$e_{i}$} (controller);
\draw [->] (system) -- node [name=q] {$q_{i}$}(output);
\draw [->] (q) |- (filter);
\draw [->] (filter) -- node {} (sum2);
\draw [->] (controller) -- node {} (sum1);
\draw [->] (sum1) -- node[name=xi] {$\xi_{i}$} (filterinv);
\node [input, below of=sum1](input2) {};
\draw [draw,->] (input2) -- node {$r_{i}$} (sum2);
\draw [->] (sum2) -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$} 
    node [near end] {$\tilde{s}_i$} (sum);
\draw [->] (delay) -| node[] {} 
    node [near end] {} (sum1);
\draw [draw,->] (input1) -- node[pos=0.15] {$u_{i-1}$} (delay);
\draw [->] (u) |- node[pos=0.99] {$u_i$} 
    node [near end] {} (output1);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you also add the list of TikZ libraries one needs?

Comment: Also, there are [several specialized libraries](https://www.ctan.org/topic/diagram-block) to draw these diagrams. I have been told the `schemabloc` is quite good.

Comment: @egreg you need to use these 2 libraries: \usetikzlibrary{arrows} \usetikzlibrary {positioning}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You already did it all the work, so I just will explain what I've changed in your code.

You used `tikset` which has been deprecated in front of `tikzstyle` (see: [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)).

The second big change was to replace `right of =` syntax by the new `right= of` from `positioning` library (section "17.5.3 Advanced Placement Options" in pgfmanual). And also used `on grid` option to better align all elements.

As I've used `on grid`, `inputs` and `outputs` are still defined as nodes with `inner sep=0pt` instead of `coordinates`. `on grid` option doesn't work as expected with `coordinates` (see: [How does the 'on grid' node positioning in TikZ actually work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76532/how-does-the-on-grid-node-positioning-in-tikz-actually-work))

The missalignment between `filter` and `sum2` node was due to using different `node distance` for `sum` nodes and all other ones. I've kept different distance but placed `filter` with a intersection coordinate `(filter) at (sum2-|filterinv)`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
    block/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle, 
            minimum height=2em, minimum width=3em},
    input/.style={inner sep=0pt},       
    output/.style={inner sep=0pt},      
    sum/.style = {draw, fill=white, circle, minimum size=2mm, node distance=1.5cm, inner sep=0pt},
    pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,thin,black}}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm, on grid, >=latex']

\node[input] (input) {};
\node[input, above = of input] (input1) {};
\node [sum, right = of input] (sum) {};
\node [block, right = of sum] (controller) {$K(s)$};
\node [sum, right = of controller] (sum1) {};
\node [block, right = of sum1] (filterinv) {$H^{-1}(s)$};
\node [block, right = 2.5cm of filterinv] (system) {$G(s)$};
\node [output, right = of system] (output) {};
\node [output, above = of output] (output1) {};
\node [block, above = of controller] (delay) {$D(s)$};
\node [sum, below = of sum1] (sum2) {};
\node [block] (filter) at (sum2-|filterinv) {$H(s)$};

\draw [draw,->] (input) node[above right] {$s_{i-1}$} -- (sum);
\draw [->] (sum) -- node {$e_{i}$} (controller);
\draw [->] (controller) -- node {} (sum1);
\draw [->] (sum1) -- node[name=xi] {$\xi_{i}$} (filterinv);
\draw [->] (filterinv) -- node[name=u, pos=.3] {$u_{i}$} (system);
\draw [->] (system) -- (output) node [name=q, above left] {$q_{i}$};

\draw [->] ([xshift=-5mm]q.south) |- (filter);
\draw [->] (filter) -- node {} (sum2);
\draw [draw,<-] (sum2) -- ++(90:.6cm) node[above]{$L_i+r_i$};

\draw [->] (sum2) -| node[pos=0.99, right] {$-$} 
    node [pos=.25, above] {$\tilde{s}_i$} (sum);

\draw [draw,->] (input1) node[above right] (ui-1) {$u_{i-1}$} -- (delay);
\draw [->] (delay) -| node[] {} 
    node [near end] {} (sum1);

\draw [->] (u.east|-system) |-  
    (output1) node[above left] (ui) {$u_i$};

\node[text=red, above left= 5mm and 6mm of ui.west] (veh) {vehicle $i$};
\draw[red, dashed] (veh.east)-|(ui.west)|-([yshift=-3mm]filter.south)-|(ui-1.east)|-(veh.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @ignasi! You explained very well your adjustments! really helpful!