# drawing a control diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, control

I want to draw a diagram like this. Could you please help me?
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question falls into the "do it for me" category, which is not well received here. There are plenty of similar questions on this very website to help you get started with this kind of diagram and I invite you to investigate them, or even look at the first examples of the [TikZ manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf). Then, if you have a specific problem with the code you have produced, people here will be glad to help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Block diagram with Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268878/block-diagram-with-tikz)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite my comment, I gave a quick try to your problem.
Here is a possible solution using TikZ:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \tikzset{%
            block/.style = {%
                rectangle,
                draw,
                align = center  
            }
        }
    
        \node[block] (pid) at (0, 0) {PID\\Controller};
        \node[
            block,
            right of      = pid,
            node distance = 3cm
        ] (plant) {Plant};
        \node[
            block,
            draw = none,
            below right of = plant,
            node distance = 2cm
        ] (obj) {Objective\\evaluation};
        \node[
            block,
            draw = none,
            below left of = pid,
            node distance = 2cm
        ] (param) {PID\\parameters};
        
        \coordinate (mid) at ($(pid)!0.5!(plant)$);
        
        \node[
            block,
            below of = mid,
            node distance = 3cm
        ] (opt) {Stochastic optimization\\techniques};
    
        \draw[-Latex] (pid.east) -- (plant.west);
        \draw[-Latex] (plant.east) -| (obj.north);
        \draw[-Latex] (obj.south) |- (opt.east);
        \draw[-Latex] (opt.west) -| (param.south);
        \draw[-Latex] (param.north) |- (pid.west);
        
        \node[
            rectangle,
            above of = mid,
            node distance = 1cm
        ] (sim) {System's simulation};
        
        \node[
            rectangle,
            draw,
            dashed,
            fit = {(pid) (sim) (plant)}
        ] {};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

yielding:

[image]

However, I really encourage you to look at [TikZ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) documentation for your future questions.
If you want to tune what I propose to your needs, please, definitely look at [TikZ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) documentation.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: @KersouMan Note  that the `of=` syntax is deprecated in favor of loading the positioning library and saying `=of`, see Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,calc,math,shapes,arrows.meta,backgrounds,positioning}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
terminal/.style={
                rectangle,
                minimum size=1cm,
                text width=2cm,
                align=center,
                very thick,
                draw=red!50!black!50, % 50% red and 50% black,
                top color=white, % a shading that is white at the top...
                bottom color=red!50!black!20, % and something else at the bottom
                font=\itshape
                 }]
\tikzstyle{myarrows}=[line width=1mm,
                      draw=blue,
                      -triangle 45,
                      postaction={draw, 
                                  line width=3mm, 
                                  shorten >=4mm, -}]

\matrix[row sep=8mm,column sep=12mm] {
     &  \node [terminal](p1) {PID\\ Controller}; 
        &
            & \node [terminal](p2) {Plant}; \\
    & 
        & \node [terminal] (p3){Stochastic Optimization Techniques};&\\
};

\draw [myarrows]                            (p1)--(p2);
\coordinate [left=1cm of p1.west]           (p){};
\draw [myarrows]                            (p2.east)--++(1cm,0)|-  
                                    node[
                                    near start,
                                    fill=white,
                                    align=center
                                    ] 
                                    {\scriptsize $Objective$\\\scriptsize $ 
                                    Evaluation$} 
                                    (p3.east);
\draw [myarrows]                    (p3.west)-| 
                                             node[
                                                 near end,
                                                 fill=white,
                                                 align=center
                                                 ] 
                                    {\scriptsize $PID$\\ \scriptsize $Parameters$}(p)- 
                                    -(p1);

\draw[dashed, ultra thick]
            (155:5cm)--++
            (0,-2cm)--++
            (10cm,0cm)--++
            (0,2cm)--
            node[
                below,
                fill=white
                ] 
                {\scriptsize $System Simulation$} 
            (155:5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT-- A black and white answer --no prettifying**

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide}%  permet de dessiner des figures, des graphiques
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,calc,math,shapes,arrows.meta,backgrounds,positioning}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[
terminal/.style={
                rectangle,
                minimum size=1cm,
                text width=2.2cm,
                align=center,
                very thick,
                draw,
                }
                    ]
\tikzstyle{myarrows}=[
                        line width=2pt,
                        draw,
                        -latex,
                        ]

\matrix[
        row sep=4cm,
        column sep=12mm
        ] 
        {%
        &\node [terminal](p1) {PID\\ Controller}; 
        &%
        &\node [terminal](p2) {Plant};                                  \\
            & 
            & \node [terminal] (p3){Stochastic Optimization Techniques};
            &                                                           \\
        };

\draw [myarrows]                            (p1)--(p2)  ;
\coordinate [left=1cm of p1.west]           (p){}       ;
\draw [myarrows]                            (p2.east)--
                                            ++(1cm,0)|-  
                                    node[
                                        near start,
                                        fill=white,
                                        align=center
                                        ] 
                                    { Objective\\ Evaluation} 
                                            (p3.east);
\draw [myarrows]                            (p3.west)-| 
                                    node[
                                        near end,
                                        fill=white,
                                        align=center
                                        ] 
                                    {PID\\ Parameters}(p)--
                                            (p1);

\draw[
        dashed, red,
        ultra thick
        ]
            ($(p1.west)+(-.5,2)$)--
            node[
                below,
                fill=white
                ] 
            {System Simulation}
            ++(10.6,0)--
            ++(0,-3)  -| 
            ($(p1.west)+(-.5,2)$)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```